# Discord command taking an integer or a string in the same argumente

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot. This bot has econnomy commands. My "withdraw" command does only work with an string as an argument. I want to take the argument "ALL" to withdraw al the money, and a integer to take an exact quanty. This is the code:

```
@commands.command()
 async def withdraw(self, ctx, cantidad):
     if type(cantidad) == int and cantidad == 0:
        await ctx.send("Put a valid value")
        return                                  
                                                    
     userStr = str(ctx.message.author)           
     current_bank_balance = database.get_user_bank(userStr)                                                           
     
     if current_bank_balance == 0:                     
         await ctx.send("You dont have money")
         return                                        
                                                          
     if cantidad == "all" or cantidad == "ALL":        
         database.withdraw(userStr, current_bank_balance)
         await ctx.send(f"You withdraw {current_bank_balance} money")
     else:                   
         database.withdraw(userStr, cantidad)
         await ctx.send(f"You withdraw {cantidad} money")
```

When you call withdraw all, the bot takes all the money to the "bank", but if you call withdraw 60 for example, this does not work

Comment: If you print `type(cantidad)` what type is it being read in as?

Comment: it just doesn't withdraw or do you get some ValueError ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     @commands.command()
     async def withdraw(self, ctx, cantidad = None):
         if cantidad == None:
             await ctx.send("You need to enter an amount")
             return
         if type(cantidad) == int and cantidad == 0:
            await ctx.send("Put a valid value")
            return                                  
                                                        
         userStr = str(ctx.author)           
         current_bank_balance = database.get_user_bank(userStr)                                                           
         
         if int(current_bank_balance) == 0:                     
             await ctx.send("You dont have money")
             return                                        
                                                              
         if str(cantidad.lower()) == 'all': """This will work for 'all' 'All' 'ALl' 'AlL' etc"""
             database.withdraw(userStr, current_bank_balance)
             await ctx.send(f"You withdraw {current_bank_balance} money")

         else:                   
             database.withdraw(userStr, int(cantidad))
             await ctx.send(f"You withdraw {cantidad} money")
```

I'm not sure if this will work but try.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a simple fix

```py
if type(cantidad) == int and cantidad == 0:
```

in this line int refers to the function int() so ur checking if type of cantidad is int() u can change int to type(1) and it should work or u could use a try except statement

```py
if type(cantidad) == type(1) and cantidad == 0:
```

```py
try:
    cantidad=int(cantidad)
    #do the stuff if it a number
except ValueError: #if cantidad is not a number
    #do the stuff if it a string
```